# Cant figure out a little css to do with the clear property

Tags: html, css

I am practicing web design and have a webpage at the url www.bigchip.co.nf and I can't work out why I cant get the button saying change date to drop down below the image and the little description. I thought that clear: right on the image of the chips would make the button drop down on a new line. Is the right way of doing this to put them into divs to seperate them?

Comment: Please share some code, for example with jsfiddle.net.

Comment: `change date` **is** below image and description for me...?  Chrome - 32.0.1700.72 m

Comment: where do u want to place the button?

Comment: I made it responsive so it seems like it works okay for certain viewport widths but when you get to a wide viewport width the change date button is to the right off the image  I want to place the button below the writing and the image like it is probably showing on some off your screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your page, i've noticed that the image is not floated which causes clear: right on it not to work.. what you can do is to add a br tag after the image element to push the change date button to the bottom of the elements.

```
<div id="container">
    <h1 id="header">BigChip.com</h1>

    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="li1"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="li2"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="li3"><a href="funny_chips.html">Funny Chips</a></li>
        <li class="li4"><a href="sign_in.html">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p id="description">
        Welcome to BigChip.com! The site with the biggest chips on the web. Get involved by uploading your own chips or browse through our gallery where your find all the chips uploaded by other users.
    </p>

    <h2 id="biggest_chip">Today's Biggest Chips!</h2>

    <img id="chipsimg" src="images/chips.jpg">
    <br />
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="change_date()">Change Date</button>

</div>
```

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for I will use the <br> element more in the future instead off wrapping everything in divs. thanks

Comment: Or you could change the display property of the image to "block" in CSS (instead of the default "Inline") which would avoid the need for additional markup.